# I am trying to prove gcd$(8,20) = 4$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, natural-numbers

I am trying to prove $\gcd(8,20) = 4$.

I am not quite sure how to go about it, but I think I need to prove that $\gcd(8,20)$ is not equal to $1$.
I have also set up $S = \{k \in \mathbb{N} : k = 8x + 10y \text{ for some } x, y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. I am trying to somehow show that $4 \in S$.

Any suggestions on how I can prove my approaches? This was a personal challenge exercise, so I am just trying to further my learning.
I did take a look at other relevant posts on here, but they are too complex or advanced in comparison to where I am at. I just learnt how to do basic proofs with axioms and proofs for natural numbers. This exercise is given near the end of practice exercises after introduction on the Well Ordering Principle and [GCD].

Thanks for any help or solutions posted!

Comment: Are you using $E$ as $\in$?

Comment: Forgive me, but the answer is 4.  And if you wish to prove this, just check all divisors of 8 against 20:  the biggest one that happens to divide 20 (i.e., 4) is the winner.

Comment: Yes I am. I couldn't find the symbol but I will fix it. thank you!

Comment: The symbol is `$\in$`.

Comment: @Randall I think it was a typo by the teacher maybe? I just copied down the question from the list for practice given.

Comment: What's the definition of $\gcd$ you're using? With the straightforward one (i.e. as the *greatest common divisor* of the two numbers), you just have to find the largest divisor of 8 that is also a divisor of 20.

Comment: If you need to work with $S$, notice that $8x+20y$ is always divisible by 4, so $S$ does not contain 1,2, or 3, but it does contain $4=8(-2)+20(1)$.

Comment: GCD is defined by gcd(a,b) := min{$k∈N : k = ax +by$ for some $x,y∈Z$}, where the set is nonempty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $d$ divides both $a$ and $b$, then $d=\gcd(a.b)$ iff $\gcd ({a\over d}, {b\over d})=1.$ Therefore, you only need to find integers $x$ and $y$ so that $2x+5y=1.$

Answer (score 0):

Since working with specific numbers, you may prove by division into cases, showing every number greater than 4 will not divide both, or use an algorithm that has been proven to give correct results, such as the Euclidean algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first state division Algorithm:  Let a, b are two integers > 0. Then there is unique integer q and r such that ${b=aq+r}$ where ${0 \leq < r <a}$ , so ${20 = 8 \cdot 2 + 4}$

- Theorem: Let a ,b are two integers > 0, and  suppose ${b=aq+r}$ for some integers q and r. then GCD(b, a)= GCD(a,r) -> GCD(20,8)=GCD(8,4), r divides a, hence GCD=4